# Could not find or load main class java on RMIServer? Bug?

Tags: java, class, package

So i'm trying to do a project for college and when i try to run it on intel ij i get the following "error : Could not find or load main class java ".
Since i'm on macbook i also have to use this flag "java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

I know this is a package related problem and i've lost so many time tried to figure this out but so far didn't solve anything.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Maicn.png)

EDIT: Sorry i didn't post the code, totally forgot
You won't be able to understand it since it's in portuguese but i guess it's not necessary.
EDIT2: if i remove the flag java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true the program runs but i get the " Can't assign requested address"

```
package rmiserver;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RMIServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMIServerInterface     {

private String MULTICAST_ADDRESS = "224.0.224.0";
private int PORT = 4321;
//public MulticastSocket socket = null;
public MulticastSocket socket2 = null;
//public int id;
public ArrayList<String> m_server;//lista de servers ativos
public Random rn;

public RMIServer() throws RemoteException {
    // id = 0;
    try {
        socket2 = new MulticastSocket(PORT);  // create socket and bind it
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
        socket2.joinGroup(group);
        //socket = new MulticastSocket();
        m_server = new ArrayList<>();
        rn = new Random();
        //new check_M(this);
        //new check_M(this);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RMIServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

//funcao usada para detetar se os servers rmi estao em baixo
public void ping() throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("caralhoooo");

}

//funcao que da print na consola do server
public void print_on_server(String s) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("> " + s);
}

// funcao que quando o cliente muda de rmi e chamada para manter o login
public void subscribe(String name) throws RemoteException {
}

public boolean login(String name, String password) throws RemoteException {
    //metodo chamado pelo cliente para dar login retorna true se o login e feito com sucesso ou falso se nao.
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|login;username|" + name + ";password|" + password + ";ID|" +id+ ";request|true;";//mensagem conforme o nosso protocolo upp
    String d = send_recive(s,id);//funcao que manda e recebe atravez da socket
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);//mudar de string para aux para ser mais facil reconhecer o pares chave valor
    d = HashToString(aux);
    System.out.println("testeeeeee->>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+d);
    if (aux.get("login_try").equals("sucess")) {
        if (aux.containsKey("notification_count")){
            if (Integer.parseInt(aux.get("notification_count")) > 0) {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public synchronized String send_recive(String s,int id) {
    //metodo que envia e recebe um datagrama
    System.out.println("entro no send_recive");
    String t = s;
    //int server = rn.nextInt(m_server.size()) + 1;
    //escolher o server aleatorio com base na lista de servers que e feita pela thread check_m
    //System.out.println("Numero aleatorio" + server);
    s = t + "mserverid|" +1;
    //System.out.println("Server escolhido " + m_server.get(server - 1));
    try {
        System.out.println("a eviar  "+s);
        send(this.socket2, this.MULTICAST_ADDRESS, this.PORT, s);
        //this.id++;
        String d = recive(this.socket2);
        //envia pacotef
        System.out.println("pacote com os xarutos "+d);
        //this.socket2.setSoTimeout(10000);
        d = recive(this.socket2);
        //recebe pacote
        HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
        aux = String_To_Hash(d);
        System.out.println("Teste "+d);
        //uso de hash map para ser mais facil a iteraçao
        System.out.println(aux.containsKey("request"));
        while (Integer.parseInt(aux.get("ID")) != id||aux.containsKey("request")) {//enquanto o id nao for igual ao id da mensagem que mandamos descartamos
            System.out.println(aux.get("ID"));
            d = recive(this.socket2);
            aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
            aux = String_To_Hash(d);
            System.out.println(id + " wow " + aux.get("ID"));
        }

        System.out.println("Saiusss");
        System.out.println(d);
        return d;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
        System.out.println("oleeeeee");
        //m_server.remove(m_server.get(server - 1));

    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        System.out.println("Socket closed " + e1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

//funcao que tenta registar uma pessoa
public boolean register(String name, String password) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("ole");
    //mensagem para registar clientes
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|register;username|" + name + ";password|" + password + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);//uso da funcao acima descrita
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("regist_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//funcao para saber se o cliente que a chamou tem ou nao permissoes de editor
public boolean is_Editor(String name) throws RemoteException {
    //
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A verificar se e editor " + name);
    String s = "type|request_permission_gerir;username|" + name + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("acess").equals("granted")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//funcao que insere um artista
public boolean insere_Artista(String name, String genero, String descricao, String data, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A inserir artista " + name);
    String s = "type|inserir_artista;username|" + username + ";artista_name|" + name + ";artista_genero|" + genero + ";artista_data|" + data + ";artista_descricao|" + descricao + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux;
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    System.out.println("Antes");
    System.out.println("Oleeeee");
    if (aux.get("insere_artista_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

public boolean insere_Grupo(String name,String genero,String descricao,String data,String artistas,String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A inserir grupo " + name);
    String s = "type|inserir_grupo;username|" + username + ";artista_name|" + name + ";artista_genero|" + genero + ";artista_data|" + data + ";artista_descricao|" + descricao + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;"+artistas;
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux;
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("insere_artista_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
public boolean insere_Musico(String name,String genero,String descricao,String data,String data_nascimento,String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A inserir musico " + name);
    String s = "type|inserir_musico;username|" + username + ";artista_name|" + name + ";artista_genero|" + genero + ";artista_data|" + data + ";artista_descricao|" + descricao + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;"+"musico_datanascimento|"+data_nascimento+";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux;
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("insere_artista_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

//fucano que remove o artista mudar isto
public boolean remove_Musico(String name, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A remover artista " + name);
    String s = "type|remover_artista;username|" + username + ";artista_name|" + name + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("remove_artista_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//fucano que remove o artista
public boolean altera_Musico(String name,String data,String descricao,String genero, String username) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("wtffffff");
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A remover artista " + name);
    String s = "type|editar_musico;username|" + username + ";musico_nome|" + name + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;"+"musico_data|"+data+";"+"musico_descricao|"+descricao+";"+"musico_genero|"+genero+";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("remove_artista_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//funcao que insere o album
public boolean insere_Album(String username, String nome, String descricao, String autor, String data) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A inserir album" + nome);
    String s = "type|inserir_album;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "album_name|" + nome + ";album_descricao|" + descricao + ";album_data|" + data + ";artista_name|" + autor + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    System.out.println("Antes");
    if (aux.get("insere_album_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//fucao que remove um album
public boolean remove_Album(String artista,String name, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A inserir album" + name);
    String s = "type|remover_album;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "album_name|" + name + ";"+"artista_name|" + artista + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    // d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("remove_album_try ").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean altera_Album(String name,String artista, String username, String nova_des, String data)  throws RemoteException {
    //System.out.println("A inserir album" + name);
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|editar_album;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "album_name|" + name + ";album_descricao|" + nova_des + ";album_data|" + data + ";"+"artista_name|" + artista + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.containsKey("user_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("user_count")); i++) {
            //mandar a notificacao para quem ja alterou o album
            Notification(this, aux.get("user_" + i + "_name"), aux.get("notification"));
        }

    }
    return false;
}

//funcao que insere musica
public boolean insere_Musica(String username, String name, String autor, String compositor, String data, String album, String descricao) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println("A inserir album" + name);
    String s = "type|inserir_musica;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "musica_name|" + name + ";musica_compositor|" + compositor + ";artista_name|" + autor + ";musica_data|" + data + ";album_name|" + album + ";musica_descricao|" + descricao + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("insere_musica_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean remove_Musica(String artista, String album, String name, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("cenas" + name);
    String s = "type|remover_musica;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "musica_name|" + name + ";"+"artista_name|" + artista + ";"+"album_name|" + album + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("remove_musica_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean altera_Musica(String artista,String album,String name,String compositor ,String descricao,String username)throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A editar_musica" + name);
    String s = "type|editar_musica;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "musica_name|" + name + ";"+"musica_compositor|" + compositor + ";"+"musica_descricao|" + descricao + ";"+"artista_name|" + artista + ";"+"album_name|" + album + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("editar_musica_try").equals("sucess")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//pesquisa que devolve todos os albuns artistas ou musicas que contem a string dada
public String Pesquisa_Geral(ArrayList<String> Albuns, ArrayList<String> Musicas, ArrayList<String> Artistas, String pesq, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A procurar " + pesq);
    String s = "type|pesquisar;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "search_key|" + pesq + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    String_to_Arrays(d, Albuns, Musicas, Artistas);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}

//pequisa a musica e devolve os detalhes da musica
public String Pesquisa_Musica(String pesq, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|get_musica;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "musica_name|" + pesq + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    // String e = "Nome da musica:" + aux.get("musica_name") + "\n" + "Album:" + aux.get("musica_album") + "\n" + "Compositor:" + aux.get("musica_compositor") + "\n" + "Descricao:" + aux.get("musica_descricao");
    return d;

}

public String Pesquisa_Album(String pesq, ArrayList<String> Musicas, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A procurar " + pesq);
    String s = "type|get_album;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "album_name|" + pesq + ";";//ou serch key
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    String e = "Nome do album:" + aux.get("album_name") + "\n" + "Autor do Album:" + aux.get("album_autor") + "\n" + "Data do album:" + aux.get("album_data");
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}

public String Pesquisa_Artista(String pesq, ArrayList<String> Albuns, String username) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println("A procurar " + pesq);
    String s = "type|get_artista;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "artista_name|" + pesq + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    String e = "Nome do artista:" + aux.get("artista_name") + "\n" + "Genero do artista:" + aux.get("artista_genero") + "\n" + "Data de nascimento:" + aux.get("artista_data");
    return d;

}

public void Make_Editor(String username, String target) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|make_editor;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "editor_name|" + target + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    if (aux.get("msg").equals("Permissoes atualizadas!")) {
        Notification(this, target, "Es editor o mano");//ver isto melhor

    }
}

public void Escreve_Critica(String username, String critica, int pont,String artista, String album) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|write_review;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "review_critica|" + critica + ";review_pontuacao|" + pont + ";album_name|" + album + ";"+"artista_name|"+artista+";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
}
public String criarPlaylist(String username, String nome_playlist,String tipo) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|make_playlist;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "playlist_name|" + nome_playlist + ";playlist_type|" + tipo + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}

public String sharePlaylist(String username, String nome_playlist,String target) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|share_playlist;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "playlist_name|" + nome_playlist + ";playlist_target|" +target + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}
public String getPlaylist(String username, String nome_playlist,String criador) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|get_playlist;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "playlist_name|" + nome_playlist + ";playlist_criador|" +criador+ ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}
public String adicionaMusicaPlaylist(String username, String nome_playlist,String artista,String album,String musica) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|musica_playlist;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "playlist_name|" + nome_playlist + ";artista_name|" +artista + ";"+"album_name|" +album + ";"+"musica_name|" +musica + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}
public String criarConcerto(String username, String local_concerto,String nome,String local_data) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|make_concerto;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "concerto_name|" + nome + ";concerto_local|" +local_concerto + ";"+"concerto_data|" +local_data + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}

public String adicionaArtistaConcerto(String username, String local_concerto,String nome,String local_data,String artista) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|artista_concerto;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "concerto_name|" + nome + ";concerto_local|" +local_concerto + ";"+"concerto_data|" +local_data + ";"+"artista_name|" +artista + ";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}

public String adicionaMusicaConcerto(String username, String local_concerto,String nome,String local_data,String artista,String album,String musica) throws RemoteException{
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|musica_concerto;username|" + username + ";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;" + "concerto_name|" + nome + ";concerto_local|" +local_concerto + ";"+"concerto_data|" +local_data + ";"+"artista_name|" +artista + ";"+"album_name|"+album+";"+"musica_name|"+musica+";";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);
    return d;
}

public String Upload_Musica(String username, String nome_musica) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|upload_music;username|" + username  +";musica_name|"+nome_musica+";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);//uma beca estupido
    return d;
}
public String Transfer_Musica(String username, String nome_musica) throws RemoteException {
    int id=rn.nextInt(10000);
    String s = "type|transfer_musica;username|" + username  +";musica_name|"+nome_musica+";ID|" + Integer.toString(id) + ";request|true;";
    String d = send_recive(s,id);
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    d = HashToString(aux);//uma beca estupido
    return d;
}

public static String HashToString(HashMap<String, String> s) {
    String r = "";
    s.remove("ID");
    s.remove("request");
    Set set = s.entrySet();
    System.out.println("Cenasssssssss");
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        System.out.print("key is: " + mentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
        System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
        r = r + mentry.getKey() + "|" + mentry.getValue() + ";";
    }
    r = r.substring(0, r.length() - 1);
    return r;
}

// =======================================================
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        RMIServerInterface s = new RMIServer();
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099).rebind("server", s);
        System.out.println("Server ready...");
    } catch (Exception re) {
        System.out.println("Exception in HelloImpl.main: " + re);
    }
}

public static void Notification(RMIServer s, String username, String notification) {

}

public static void String_to_Arrays(String d, ArrayList<String> Albuns, ArrayList<String> Musicas, ArrayList<String> Artistas) {
    //album_count|3;item_0_name|Gotta Jazz ;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    if (aux.containsKey("album_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("album_count")); i++) {
            System.out.println("album_" + i + "_name");
            Albuns.add(aux.get("album_" + i + "_name"));
        }
    }
    if (aux.containsKey("artista_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("artista_count")); i++) {
            System.out.println("artista_" + i + "_name");
            Artistas.add(aux.get("artista_" + i + "_name"));
        }
    }
    if (aux.containsKey("musica_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("musica_count")); i++) {
            System.out.println("musica_" + i + "_name");
            Musicas.add(aux.get("musica_" + i + "_name"));
        }
    }

}

public static void String_to_Arrays_Albuns(String d, ArrayList<String> Albuns) {
    //album_count|3;item_0_name|Gotta Jazz ;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    if (aux.containsKey("album_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("album_count")); i++) {
            System.out.println("album_" + i + "_name");
            Albuns.add(aux.get("album_" + i + "_name"));
        }
    }
}

public static void String_to_Arrays_Artistas(String d, ArrayList<String> Artistas) {
    //album_count|3;item_0_name|Gotta Jazz ;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    if (aux.containsKey("artista_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("artista_count")); i++) {
            System.out.println("artista_" + i + "_name");
            Artistas.add(aux.get("artista_" + i + "_name"));
        }
    }

}

public static void String_to_Arrays_Musicas(String d, ArrayList<String> Musicas) {
    //album_count|3;item_0_name|Gotta Jazz ;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie;item_1_name|Boogie Woogie
    HashMap<String, String> aux = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aux = String_To_Hash(d);
    if (aux.containsKey("musica_count")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(aux.get("musica_count")); i++) {
            System.out.println("musica_" + i + "_name");
            Musicas.add(aux.get("musica_" + i + "_name"));
        }
    }
}

//ta mal
public static void send(MulticastSocket socket, String MULTICAST_ADDRESS, int PORT, String s) {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = s.getBytes();
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, group, PORT);//adicionar port
        System.out.println("a enviar --------------->>>>>");
        socket.send(packet);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static HashMap<String, String> String_To_Hash(String s) {

    HashMap<String, String> r = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] parts = s.split(";");
    //chave1|valor1;chave2|valor dois
    String[] parts2;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        parts2 = parts[i].split("\\|");
        r.put(parts2[0], parts2[1]);
    }
    return r;
}

public static String recive(MulticastSocket socket) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    socket.receive(packet);

    String message = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
    HashMap<String, String> aux = String_To_Hash(message);
    System.out.println("recive hahahahah "+message);
    if (aux.containsKey("request")) {
        return message;
    } else {
        return message;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Does your code have a class containing a method defined `public static void main(String[] args)`? Where is it? Please show your code

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't show the code in the first place. My bad.